# how to compare value obtained from Option[Long] scala

Tags: scala

This is the code snippet:

```
OS.config flatMap {_.Allocation } flatMap {_.memory}
```

The value obtained from the `memory` parameter is `Option[Long]`.

How can I compare and check if it is greater than zero?

I tried using filter, but the answer obtained is `Option[Boolean]`. I need to check for many objects and if the value is greater than zero increment the counter.

Comment: What if the `Option[Boolean]` is `None`?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `exists` method. This method, when run on an option, takes a function that returns a boolean. If your Option is a None, it will return false.

eg.

```
scala> var x = Some(123)
x: Some[Int] = Some(123)

scala> x.exists(_ > 0)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> x.exists(_ < 0)
res1: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `fold` over it to either get `false` if it hasn't been specified or check if it's greater than `0`:

```
(OS.config flatMap {_.Allocation } flatMap {_.memory}).fold(false)(_ > 0)
```